# Improvement of search and search results

Tags: feature-request, search

I know that search have many advanced options as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching). But I would like to see some improvements in search such as:

- some sort of autocomplete when several terms are entered within the search field (like the one when we ask a question, for instance)
- user could be retrieved too (sometimes, I'm looking for answers of a particular user) and outline either via this autocomplete or by adding a tab "user" within the search results

Also, search is sometimes not very robust; especially when words that are common within code blocks are used within the query (for instance: `max length file S3` returns results that essentially contains those keyword within code blocks). There is a `hascode:` option, it would be great to exclude code blocks from search.

Comment: This is too broad. Please split this into several feature requests, each asking for a specific feature. (e.g. "Add tag autocomplete when I type `[` in the search box" etc.)